# (Android) Horizontal Progress Bar - XML return null (black screen on device)

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

my progress bar is not working when I set the values in a xml.

First, when I make a instance programatically works:

```
LinearLayout progressBarLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);
progressBarLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);

progressBar.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));
final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
ShapeDrawable pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("yellow"));
ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(progress);
progressBar.setProgress(activity.getModel().getProgress());
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
progressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
progressBarLayout.addView(progressBar);
bodyLayout.addView(progressBarLayout);
```

But when I use xml:

**Layout:**

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>   android:background="@android:color/white"
>   android:orientation="vertical"
>   android:padding="10dp" >
>
>   <ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
>        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
>        android:layout_width="match_parent"
>        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>        android:maxHeight="30dp"
>        android:minHeight="30dp"
>        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_drawable">
>   </ProgressBar>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

**Drawable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                    android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff747674"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
    >
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#33FF33"
                    android:endColor="#008000"
                    android:angle="270" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**CODE in JAVA:**

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setProgress(activity.getModel().getProgress());
bodyLayout.addView(progressBarLayout);
```

This give me a exception (black screen) and I don't know why.
The code in java is in the class Viewer.
And I have a activity Controller that instance the Viewer:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("innnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnfo", "menu");
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
            detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);
            this.mUser = (MaritacaUser) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Constants.USER_DATA);
            if (mUser != null) {
                InputStream file = getResources().getAssets().open(Constants.FORM_FILENAME);    
                setModel(new Model(file));
                if (!getModel().isQuestionsEmpty()) {
                    viewer = new Viewer(ControllerActivity.this, getModel()
                            .getCurrentQuestion());
                }
                setContentView(viewer.getView());
            }       
        } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new MaritacaException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I think the **(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);** is returning null, but in the R class shows the ProgressBar. I can't find the error on this code, maybe I have to instance the ProgressBar in the activity and not in the viewer?